# Hide a Bootstrap Modal after a Patial View return from an Ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-ajax

When I make an ajax call, I show my modal (options.beforeSend). But, when I get an ajax result error (options.error) I would like to hide this modal. I've tryied but no success.

Index.cshtml

```
@* Modal - load spin *@
<div class="modal fade" id="itemLoader" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body d-inline text-center">
                <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-info" role="status">
                <span class="sr-only small"></span>
                </div>
                <span class="far fa-dizzy fa-3x text-secondary" style="display:none;"></span>
                <label id="ModalStatus">Loading...</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Before send I toggle/show the modal:

```
  options.beforeSend = function (xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", 
        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        
        // My modal (works fine)
        $('#itemLoader').modal('toggle');
        $('#itemLoader').modal('show');
    };
    
    options.success = function (data) {
        if (data.idOrder!= null) {
            window.location.href = "/app/order/order?Id=" + data.idOrder;
        }
    };
```

If error (after a partial view return, from ModelState is not valid), I am trying to hide the modal, but I can't:

```
    options.error = function (res) {
               
        // When my modelState is not valid, return partial view with required messages (working fine)
        $('#chkForm').html(res.responseText);
       
        // But I can't hide the modal (does not work)
        var modal = $("#itemLoader");
        modal.hide();

        // hide modal (does not work)
        $('#itemLoader').modal('hide');
        $('#itemLoader').hide();
    };
```

I have tryied the close button on modal, but no sucess as well:

```
 <button id="btnclosemodal" class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
 </button>

// Does not work
$('#btnclosemodal').click(); 

// Does not work
$("#btnclosemodal").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: So, at this point, I want to know are you hitting the error event on the xhr that you have? can you alert or log something there?

Comment: Do you think those errors have influence on hide modal?

Comment: The code that worked for me was  
            $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
            $('#itemLoader').modal('dispose');

Answer (score 1):

`error` function will be called if the request fails. I think here it will not enter the error function since it return the partial view normally. You can use f12 and debug it in the source tab.

Instead, I think you should hide the modal in the success function.

Comment: The return of my Partial View heppends when my ModelView is not valid, so the function erros is called. I fixed my problem using $('.modal-backdrop').hide(); $('#itemLoader').modal('dispose'); By the way, tks for the help. And I have changed some code using success function as you told me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to toggle the modal on error, like this:
`$('#itemLoader').modal('toggle');`

Comment: Doesn't  work. Don't know if the problem has something about the use of Partial View.